# Unity jagged mouse input detection

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote a script that writes Input.mousePosition into a file on every frame. The idea is that I want to identify which button on screen the player is trying to click before actually clicking, from the speed of the mouse basically. However, I ran into data like this:

```
(1113.0, 835.0, 0.0)
(1113.0, 835.0, 0.0)
(1113.0, 835.0, 0.0)
(1126.0, 835.0, 0.0)
```

Basically on one frame the x position is one value, a couple of frames later it's changed, but in the middle there is no gradation. While my mouse movement was continuous, if I'm to believe Unity, in the example above I hovered on 1 pixel for 3 frames then jumped 13 pixels to the right in one frame. Why is this? Is there any code to get the actual frame by frame position of the mouse?

EDIT:

```
    Vector2 _lastPosition;
    StreamWriter _mouseData;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
        {
        _mouseData = new StreamWriter(File.Open("sdata.txt", FileMode.Create));
        }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
        {
        _mouseData.WriteLine(Input.mousePosition.ToString());
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
            _mouseData.WriteLine("CLICK\n\n");
            }

        _lastPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }

    void OnDestroy()
        {
        _mouseData.Close();
        }
```

EDIT 2:
I changed the code to the following:

```
void FixedUpdate()
        {           
        _mouseData.WriteLine(Vector2.SqrMagnitude(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"))));

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
            _mouseData.WriteLine("CLICK\n\n");
            }
        }
```

Now I'm still getting output that's 50% 0-es and non-0 values are sprinkled in on every second row. Exceptions: a few rows where actual values are supposed to be still contain random 0-es. Now, I'm not super concerned about getting less frequent than 1/frame data, but there's no way to distinguish between these false 0-es and actual 0-es when the mouse is not moving, which is an issue.

Comment: If this is for a practical purpose, could you not use raycasting with raycast padding if you want some tolerance?

Comment: I've seen mouse bugs in Unity many times (even the same app getting different results from one machine to another)... and still no clue what is causing it. Are you getting the same behaviour if you don't write the position to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find out from your question but I am guessing that you use the `FixedUpdate()` method which is unreliable in this situation. `Update()` is advised to use for calls that you want to execute once per frame.

**EDIT:**
Also, note that it is recommended that you set your application's framerate to a realistic number since it is [unlimited by default (on desktop)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html) and your app could be running with so many FPS that it is faster than how often you can sample your mouse input.

You can set the framerate using: `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;`

Aside from this problem it is generally a good idea to set your framerate to save yourself some headaches. (This is specifically true if you develop for mobile platforms and test on your desktop.)

Comment: Funny you should say, I tried both. Same thing :) But I'll post the code.

Comment: Absolutely not true... `Update` fires every frame... `FixedUpdate` fires at every physics interval (60 per second by default).

Comment: @Shomz Sorry, I mixed the two up. You are right and I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No problem! Btw. it still doesn't answer the question because OP told you he tried both ways and got the same results... the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Actually I just checked and this almost never happens in the fixedupdate version. I happened to find something similar almost immediately and I thought it was the same. But the datasets actually look much better with that. Sorry about the misinformation.

Comment: @zoliking Did you meant to accept this answer? Your comment suggests you disagree with its recommendation to use `Update`.

Comment: It seemed to solve the issue at the time, but I'm still having issues. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you set the framerate of your application? You could be running with so many FPS that it's faster than how often you can sample your mouse input. 
You can set it using: `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;`

Comment: @Zserbinator That seems to have hit the nail on the head. If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you!!! I've been stuck on this for waaay too long :D

Comment: @zoliking I'm glad that this solved it, I edited my answer.

Comment: @zoliking Yup :D

Comment: @Zserbinator Mik az esélyek? :D :D :D